# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.File.toPath()

Tags: java, file, file-upload

There was a problem when I used the Stream-upload plugin to upload file
.Questions are as follows:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.File.toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path;
```

environment:  **jdk 1.7 + tomcat 6.0 + MyExclipse**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The method was introduced in Java 7 - you are probably compiling with an older compiler (check your eclipse settings)...

Comment: don't post a link to a picture of some code. Include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toPath method requires Java 7. Make sure you are using the same version of Java across the machine.

Comment: @AlisonGavin is your problem resolved?  If yes please have to look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you. Thanks very much!  谢谢！